# C# File.AppendAllText produces corrupted file

Tags: c#

I am trying to append some lines to a *.doc file using:

```
foreach (var user in usersApproved)
    File.AppendAllText(Server.MapPath(("..\\Files\\TFFiles\\" + tid + "\\" + file.Type + "\\")) + Path.GetFileName(file.Title), "Document Signed by: " + user.UserName + Environment.NewLine);
```

But it produces a corrupted file.

**EDITS**

I used this answer to produce a `*.docx` file. But when I try to append the lines I receive the error that "...the file is used by another process" so it fails

The machine is a server where I don't want to install Word/Office so Office Interop is not a viable option.

Comment: What do you mean by corrupted? I don't think you can treat a `.doc` file as a simple text file. You should use some interop libraries

Comment: Doc file is not plaintext file, it has specific format. So you can't just append some text at the end of it and expect it will work.

Comment: Word document file is a **binary** file, not plaintext one. You need to use other way like Office integration to create and add text inside it.

Comment: Ok thank you I missed that... I will try with openxml

Comment: @aggicd I don't think OpenXML would help. A doc file isn't XML, unless you're talking about a docx file.

Comment: @john I dont want to use microsoft interop because it causes some problems on the server. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Free and opensource: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=npoi

Comment: If cannot install word on the server you should either consider migrating to docx or implementing a non-microsoft .doc API like @Nekeniehl suggests

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that what you need is the Document.Add method. You can read about it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.documents.add(v=office.14).aspx

If I'm not mistaken, you are trying to treat your file as a common text file while the .doc is a MSWord document

Comment: I dont want to use microsoft interop because I dont want to install office on server

Comment: Youcan also try WordprocessingDocument found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.wordprocessingdocument(v=office.14).aspx.

You can use this for .docx files.

I'm not at work right now to test and see if this works but you can try and see how it treats .doc files

Comment: @Mouse `WordprocessingDocument` looks like related to openxml sdk, so .doc would not work, only docx would work with `WordprocessingDocument`.